# Android - Prevent Softkeyboard from closing after EditText has been disabled

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I am trying a very simple UI, there is an `EditText` and an `ImageView`. When I click on the EditText I would like to accept input from the the user. Now when I click on the ImageView (while the keyboard is still open) I would like to disable the EditText and at the same time prevent the softkeyboard from closing. However setEnabled(false) automatically closes the softkeyboard.

Here is my Acitivity:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                editText.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the UI:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.pearson.android.test.stackoverflow_efficient_data_construction_recyclerview.SecondActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_second">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried keeping the softkeyboard open like so:

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.toggleSoftInput (InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

but there is a very noticable flicker (as though the old keyboard closes and is replaced by a new one).

I also tried not to disable the EditText (I should not be able to input any text after clicking on the Image) and tried manipulating its focasability instead, but without success.

Any direction or a solution would be most appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to keep the soft keyboard open, even though the user isn't supposed to be able to type into it? That's bad design and the user won't know what's going on.

Comment: I'm actually struggling with the same issue. As an example: there are 4 buttons, each button shows a new Search EditText in place of the old one. The old one animates out and is disabled and the new animates in. I want to keep the keyboard up as the EditText field is changing. None of the mentioned methods work.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code to hide the key board

```
  imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               hideKeyboard(getContext());
            }
        });
public static void hideKeyboard(Context ctx) {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) ctx
                    .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            View v = ((Activity) ctx).getCurrentFocus();
            if (v == null)
                return;

            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
```

Comment: I do not want to hide the keyboard, I want to do quite the opposite, keep it open even after disabling the EditText

Comment: InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);

Comment: Typical SO answer for the problem from nowhere. Why did it even not -1000'minusized?
There are no solution and this answer should be deleted